# Open image size links in a page instead of direct image link

Tags: functions, attachments, images

I am using this custom function to display image sizes on image.php (attachment page)

```
   function my_get_image_size_links() {

    /* If not viewing an image attachment page, return. */
    if ( !wp_attachment_is_image( get_the_ID() ) )
        return;

    /* Set up an empty array for the links. */
    $links = array();

    /* Get the intermediate image sizes and add the full size to the array. */
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    $sizes[] = 'full';

    /* Loop through each of the image sizes. */
    foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {

        /* Get the image source, width, height, and whether it's intermediate. */
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID(), $size );

        /* Add the link to the array if there's an image and if $is_intermediate (4th array value) is true or full size. */
        if ( !empty( $image ) && ( true == $image[3] || 'full' == $size ) )
            $links[] = "<a class='image-size-link' href='{$image[0]}' target=_blank>{$image[1]} &times; {$image[2]}</a>";
    }

    /* Join the links in a string and return. */
    return join( ' <span class="sep">/</span> ', $links );
}
```

On the attachment page, when I click on the image size (rezolutions like 1602 × 1200 / 1920 × 1437 / 1442 × 1080 / 150 × 150 / 2580 × 1932), it will open the image, like for example site.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/randomimage-1602×1200.jpg

But instead of opening site.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/randomimage-1602×1200.jpg directly, I want it to open a page where that image size will be posted.

Anyone knows how to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer (actually paid a programmer to do it)
 modify to

```
/* Add the link to the array if there's an image and if $is_intermediate (4th array value) is true or full size. */
if ( !empty( $image ) && ( true == $image[3] || 'full' == $size ) )
$links[] = "<a class='image-size-link' href='/show-image.php?path={$image[0]}' target=_blank>{$image[1]} &times; {$image[2]}</a>";
}
```

create a file, upload it in your root (or where you want) and add this code in it:

"/>

hope this helps!